# How to define setOnAction for tableView rows?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am writing a program with javafx and tableView feature.

My purpose is when I click on a row of this table,another window opens and shows something but I don't know how to define something like setOnMouseClicked feature for my table.

I searched a lot but I coudn't find a simple way

This is my existing code that define table columns and rows.(rows are defined with observable feature)

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TableView tableView = new TableView();

    TableColumn<String, Account> column1 = new TableColumn<>("UserName");
    column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userName"));
    column1.setMinWidth(100);

    TableColumn<String, Account> column2 = new TableColumn<>("PassWord");
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("passWord"));
    column2.setMinWidth(100);


    tableView.getColumns().add(column1);
    tableView.getColumns().add(column2);
    tableView.setItems(getAllAccounts());



    VBox vbox = new VBox(tableView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox,200,200);
    Stage window ;

    window = primaryStage;

    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}
private ObservableList<Account> getAllAccounts(){
ObservableList<Account> accounts= FXCollections.observableArrayList(Account.getAccounts());
return accounts;

}


}
```

Comment: Note that you used the wrong order of type parameters for `TableColumn`: The first type parameter should match the type parameter of the `TableView` (which matches the type of the items, i.e. `Account` in this case), the second the type returned by the getter (probably `String`). In addition to listening to clicks, listening to the selected item may be an option. The behaviour is a bit different though...

Comment: @fabian Yes You're right,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two options:

> **Method 1:**

Implement a click listener on the `TableView` and retrieve the item that was selected.

```
// Listen for a mouse click and access the selectedItem property
tblAccounts.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    // Make sure the user clicked on a populated item
    if (tblAccounts.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
        System.out.println("You clicked on " + tblAccounts.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getUsername());
    }
});
```

> **Method 2:**

Create your own `RowFactory` for the `TableView` and handle your logic there. *(I prefer this method)*

```
// Create a new RowFactory to handle actions
tblAccounts.setRowFactory(tv -> {

    // Define our new TableRow
    TableRow<Account> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("Do your stuff here!");
    });
    return row;
});
```

---

Method #1 is the simplest approach and will work for most needs. You'll want to use method #2 for more complex needs, such as styling the individual rows, or to handle clicks on empty rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help , how can I implement a click listener for tableView?

Comment: Thanks a lot,one little question,My getUserName Method doesn't work,What can be the reason

Comment: In method #2 you should proably check for an empty row. Otherwise `row.getItem()` could yield unexpected results...

Comment: @fabian Thanks a lot